# When i ckeck a checkbox all checkboxes are checked (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkbox, uicollectionview

Hello i have a collection view in which i have a checkbox in every cell.
I use this checkbox https://github.com/zhouhao27/WOWCheckbox.

All cells have their checkbox but the problem as the title says is that when i tap on the checkbox all checkboxes are checked.
Actually when i tap the first all odds checkboxes (1-3-5-7-...) are checked and when i tap the second then all checkboxes are checked.

I connected the view to my cell file i change it to WOWCheckbox as the documentation says.

I didn't change anything else.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Interest Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThirdTabCell


        cell.check1.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.check1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ThirdTab.follow(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        return cell



    }




func follow(sender:WOWCheckbox!) {
        print("check")
    }
```

When i use this code when i tap a checkbox it  prints check only once.
I believe i somehow i have to declare which check i tap but i don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
   // func follow(sender:WOWCheckbox!) {
    //     sender.tag//will get the which row you checked
     //do logic based on tag
     //}
```

//Create model

```
class checkList{
   var item = ""
   var checked = false
}
```

//Controller

```
class SampleViewController: ViewController,WOWCheckboxDelegate{

  var List = [checkList]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      for i in 1...10 {
        let object = checkList()
        object.item = i.description
        object.checked = false 
        List.append = obj
    }
    _collectionview.reloadData()
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Interest Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThirdTabCell


    cell.check1.tag = indexPath.row
    if List[indexPath.row].checked {
     cell.check1.isChecked = true
    }
    else{
     cell.check1.isChecked = false
    }

    return cell
   }
   //delegate function by WOWCheckbox
    func didSelectCheckbox(checkbox : WOWCheckbox) {

        if checkBox.tag == 0{
        //first row 
        for i ...< List.count {
           if i % 2 != 0 {
               List[i].checked = true
           }
           else{
                List[i].checked = false
           }
            collectionView.reloadData()
            return
          }
        }
       //second row
        else if checkBox.tag == 1{

           for obj in List {
           obj.checked = true
          }
          collectionView.reloadData()
          return
        }
        else {
           if list[checkbox.tag].isChecked {
           checkBox.isChecked = false
           list[checkbox.tag].checked = false
           }
           else{
             list[checkbox.tag].checked = true
             checkBox.isChecked = true
           }
         }
        }
    }
```

i didn't tested please check the code and change according to your requirement

Comment: thank you for you answer but i can't really understand you..can you please explain it more?

Comment: the check is done before the call of the function 
I tried without any of my code and stills check it all

Comment: tag is used for identify which check box is selected. (cell.check1.tag = indexPath.row) you already given for that.so when click on checkBox it will call follow method.in that method you will get which checkbox is selected. so you can do your logic based on what you mentioned in your question.

Comment: ok I understand that but it hasn't any command to check the box..it does it automatically

Comment: what you getting when click on the checkbox in follow method? .check wowCheckBox methods if any method to check all checkboxes.

Comment: With this command check.isChecked = true i make checkbox checked but the thing is that it check it all before the function